# Migrating ASP to ASP.Net MVC - Identify Model/View/Controllers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Currently working on a Classic ASP to ASP.NET MVC 3 migration project. Well! As all of you know Classic ASP page contains all the layer codes (DAL, BAL) in one single file. I'm little bit confused here also beginner in MVC. For views, we can use (markup of) the asp pages which all can be rendered to the user. Just struggled to identify the Controller and Models. Is there any easy way exist to identify Controller/Models ?

I give a small example. 
1) After login of the user, say one asp file (role.asp) check the roles of that user.
2) Then it will redirect to another page (say next.asp) which will get data for the user from db and store it in session then redirect to the landing page ( land.asp). 
**Note** that landing page will differ based on role.

In the above scenario there are 3 files are involved. How can i identify the Controller/model/view here. :( Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to migrate asp to asp.net because of big differences in approach (script vs controller/model) and language (vbscript vs vb.net/c#). This topic has been already [discussed and answered many times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532227/how-to-migrate-existing-asp-net-application-to-asp-net-mvc-pattern-format).

Regarding your example: all this even in asp does not require multiple scripts. In MVC it could be also done with one controller and 1-2 views.

E.g.

- View - Login (shows login form)
- View - Land (shows land form)
- Controller - Home

  - ActionResult Method - Login (show login form)
  - ActionResult Method - Authenticate (proceed login form and do what does role.asp and next.asp)
  - ActionResult Method - Land

Comment: thanks for the reply. The url you gave talk about the migration from ASP.Net to ASP.Net MVC. Not speak about Classic ASP to ASP.Net MVC. However you guide me how to construct the controllers for my problem. Thanks!