# How to migrate from WebForms to MVC, step by step?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, asp.net-mvc-5, migration

I'm having already existing project (of medium size) that is created using WebForms. Now I have to gradually migrate it to MVC5. I should start section by section, site by site, and at the end to got to the point where it will be fully in MVC.

I'm having intermediate knowledge of MVC and basic/intermediate knowledge of WebForms. I guess these will be the steps:

```
1.) to create empty MVC5 solution
2.) integrate WebForms project into new MVC5 solution
3.) make WebForms and MVC5 run side by side (make sure that old system works correctly while it's part of MVC5 solution)
4.) modifying WebForms project, section by section (site by site) and converting them one by one to MVC patterns
```

In theory I think I got the idea, but in the code I'm really not sure how to start the integration. All I did so far is step 1 :) 
I have take a look into this link: 
[Combine ASP.Net MVC with WebForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203411/combine-asp-net-mvc-with-webforms?rq=1), but it did helped me a lot since the blog post from @jeroenh maybe can help me in `step3` but not in the `step2`. For `step2` I have tried to apply the post from @Matt in the same link, but I end-up with a lot of [errors](http://prntscr.com/apocle) (at his step6) and a lot of effort, so I'm thinking I'm not on the right track.

Are there some posts/tutorials related to this, step by step, that will guide the developers from doing this WebForms and MVC running side by side (but in one project and not in different projects)?

Comment: Maybe this article will help you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991978.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532227/how-to-migrate-existing-asp-net-application-to-asp-net-mvc-pattern-format refer this very good answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to migrate existing asp.net application to asp.net MVC pattern format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532227/how-to-migrate-existing-asp-net-application-to-asp-net-mvc-pattern-format)

Comment: I am not sure what you really mean by MVC5 (because ASP.NET's versioning is a mess) but there is a VS extension to help you upgrade (old) .net applications to the latest versions of .net: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.upgradeassistant