# Best way to intregrate ASP.NET MVC with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been assigned to change a section in an existing `ASP.NET` website. The requirement is to use `ASP.NET MVC` for that section. We are thinking to divide it in different modules where some of them will be in `ASP.MVC` and the others with remain the same for some time, until we have time to change the whole website into `ASP.NET MVC` application.

- Does anybody have any idea which is the best way to combine both of them in a way that the different sections will be in `MVC` and some in simple `ASP.NET` ?
- Secondly if anybody has any idea how to solve routing problems to redirect from `ASP.NET` --> `MVC` part and vice verca ?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC is part of ASP.NET already. Perhaps you are confusing Web Forms with ASP.NET?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/532227/654031

Comment: yes exactly, I am talking for webforms. I googled the question but did not find it. So I will check it and let you know if I have anything to add... Thanks for the answer

Comment: I am not setting it to work yet, and I dont know where is the problem. Here is what I did: Installed MVC 4 from nuget `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 4.0.30506` since the project is .NET 4. After that I created two folders Controllers and Views. And then added the RegisterRoutes method where I registered my controller, but when i buld it it does not get hit and furthermore it shows me `HTTP 404 error: The resource cannot be found.` I think it is looking for .aspx file and does not find it. When run it in debug mode the breakpoints are not hit showing 'No symbol has been loaded.'

Comment: Hi guys, I just found the problem. The controller folder needs to be placed in `App_Code folder`. I dont know why!