# Code-behind in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm rebuilding a small project which is built using `.aspx`, i'm simply converting it to Razor(manually - converters do not work.)

In the `.aspx project` I have `code-behind` a page & an `auto-generated` file that start as follow:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated. 
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Question, do I just create a new controller file and add the `Code-behind` and ignore the `auto-generated file`? I'd really appreciate your guidance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to migrate existing asp.net application to asp.net MVC pattern format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532227/how-to-migrate-existing-asp-net-application-to-asp-net-mvc-pattern-format)

Comment: You might also find this article helpful:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991978.aspx

Comment: Hi amy, thank you for your response, however my question is very different from your suggested urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

In Windows Forms and Web Forms, the `designer.cs` are only there for the visual designer and the components of the form. If you are moving to MVC, there is no use for any of that code since you will not be able to use anything from there.